# How do I create an Elastic Beanstalk example?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, elastic-beanstalk, aws-ec2

I have tried to create and deploy on Elastic Beanstalk. It never works. I have spent over 14 hours trying to get EB to work over the course of 1 month. I have followed online tutorials in addition to the tutorials in AWS documentation, both for "real" deployments and the simple example deployments. I have never successfully gotten anything to work with Elastic Beanstalk.

The most recent error, trying to create the simplest possible example deployment, is this:

October 15, 2023 22:07:57 (UTC-5)   ERROR   LaunchWaitCondition failed. The expected number of EC2 instances were not initialized within the given time. Rebuild the environment. If this persists, contact support.
October 15, 2023 22:07:56 (UTC-5)   ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-[...]-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

Comment: Hey BigMistake, I'm sorry to hear that you're having trouble with Elastic Beanstalk. Ensure that you haven't reached your AWS account's resource limits, the maximum number of instances you're allowed to run, i mean. You can check your limits in the AWS Management Console.

Comment: @R1w I'm not close to the limits

Comment: There aren't many logs that could assist in pinpointing the underlying issue. I attempted to provide you with guidance in the hope that it might aid you in resolving the problem. Feeling stuck can be quite disheartening.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:
Check the logs for your environment, which can provide more detailed error messages. You can access these logs through the AWS Management Console or by using the AWS CLI, and if there more logs, please comment.
Make sure your VPC and subnet configurations are correctly set up. Make sure your Elastic Beanstalk environment is using subnets that have outbound internet access and that your security groups allow the necessary traffic.
If you've attached custom policies to your Elastic Beanstalk instances, ensure that they aren't interfering with the launch process.
Verify that the Elastic Beanstalk service role has the necessary permissions to create EC2 instances and associated resources. Also, check that your IAM roles and policies are correctly set up for your application.
Verify that your Elastic Beanstalk environment configuration, including the key parameters in your `.ebextensions` or Elastic Beanstalk configuration file. Ensure that all settings are correct.